# MySQL Optimization for 1-to-* Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

Ok, I've been trying to figure this out but haven't been able to come to a conclusion. I'd love to get some results from y'all, tips to do some more testing, or some more resources to read.

The situation is simple. There is a primary table of pictures. Probably of `cat_pictures`. There is a secondary table of `cat_pictures_comments`. Some smart developer made sure that `cat_pictures` has an auto-incrementing primary key of `ID_PICTURE`, and comments are stored with an index of `ID_PICTURE` as well.

Our application has a page that wants to show all of the pictures with all of each pictures comment.

Do we

1. Just `INNER JOIN` `cat_pictures` with `cat_pictures_comments`(and make sure things are ordered correctly)
2. Get all `cat_pictures`, then loop through each and get `cat_pictures_comments` for each picture

A: What if the application is PHP?

B: What if `cat_pictures` had the entry ID, picture filepath, and another 20,285 fields for the cat's genome? And the `cat_pictures` were also `INNER JOIN`'ed with each cat's owner's psychiatrist (a 1-1 relationship). ( Basically, there's way more data attached to the primary table compared to our little pissant comments table. )

Thanks all.

Comment: The question is unclear. The answer is join. Consider providing an annexe table for 1-1 data, but only if it can be demonstrated that there's a significant performance benefit. If in doubt, test.

Comment: Sorry. That's what I'm saying, I'm not sure how to measure the benefit of using PHP to get each pictures comments or using the query to get it. I get the impression that PHP *could* be better since the memory to store and return the duplicated `cat_pictures` data could far outweigh the small size of each comment attached to the picture.

Comment: While possible, in practice, that assumption is incredibly unlikely. Generally, the fewer 'round trips' to the DB the better - with '1' being optimum.

Comment: <Generally, the fewer 'round trips' to the DB the better - with '1' being optimum>
For the sake of making this question useful, any tips for properly benchmarking that "assertion?" Should we see that time and/or memory is improved? Also factoring in caching and optimization in PHP and caching and memory in MySQL... also considering super-dynamic tenant systems

Comment: It's quite straightforward to make, say, a couple of million row (and indexed) tables, and just see what you get. Beyond that, it's for others to say because  benchmarking and optimisation are not really my turf.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is, do you join back to the comments and then have a query that looks like

Option 1

```
select (all pic columns), (all comment columns) from pics inner join comments;
```

Vs. Option 2

```
Select * from pics; then loop and select * from comments were pictureId = @currentId;
```

Vs. Option 3

```
Select * from pics order by picId; select * from comments order by picId;
```

In option 1, you have every column of the picture table duplicated for every comment that has been posted for that picture. If there are many comments for each picture and the picture table is very wide, then you will likely be better off to pull two separate datasets from the database.

In option 2, you would be making too many round trips to the database if there were many pictures.

Based on the lack of complete requirements, I would recommend option 3. Get the picture table results and comments as two separate datasets, and then in your php page: loop through each pic and display pic info, then nested loop to get the comments for the current picture from the local dataset of comments that has already been pulled from SQL Server.

Comment: I cannot see the logic of favouring 3 over 1. I think you'd struggle to devise a scenario in which 3 out- performed 1, but would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @Strawberry, I feel like 3 *could* outperform 1 if the data returned in the "primary" table is excessive... if the amount of data in it creates a large enough data overhead. No? Because for each comment, that data is duplicated in the output

Comment: Other RDBMSs may be better. Nevertheless, MySQL loves (properly indexed) data. And it's very good at processing it. It will beat PHP hands down.

Comment: Option 3 is still allowing MySQL to do the processing. It is just having MySQL return the data in a more normalized dataset bc the pictures parent table has so many columns. It was mentioned that the pictures table could have over 20 thousand columns, so if you have 10 comments per picture over 11 pictures, then that is over 2 million extra/duplicated data points you returning in option 1 vs option 3.  Add a few more pictures, comments per picture, and concurrent users, and the overhead of that duplicated data in option 1 outweighs the cost of two separate (but still fast) queries.